# Entity Framework On Update : Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

i am having below model :-

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public Guid Id
            {
                get;
                set;
            }protected BaseClass()
            {
                if (Guid.Empty==Id)
                {
                    Id = LongGuid.NewGuid();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Product : BaseClass
        {

          // other properties like name and price.
          private Recipe _recipe;
            public virtual Recipe Recipe
            {
                get
                {    
                    return this._recipe;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._recipe = value;
                }
            }

            private InventoryItem _inventoryItem;
            public virtual InventoryItem InventoryItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._inventoryItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._inventoryItem = value;
                }
            }
public class InventoryItem  : BaseClass
{
 // Name and value 
}

public class Recipe : BaseClass
{
 // Name and value 
}
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InventoryItem> InventoryItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

I am saving as below :-

```
this._workspace.Update(Model);
this._context.SaveChanges();
```

When i create product with InventoryItem and Recipe its work well.

but when i create product without InventoryItem and Recipe and save in database and after sometime i try to update product  with new InventoryItem () and new Recipe () i am getting below error :-

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

Inner Error :-

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because EF cannot determine how to relate your Product to your Recipe and InventoryItem. To work through this, temporarily remove your InventoryItem and get your product and recipe persisting as expected.

With EF 6 and Core you have the option of defining a FK field in the parent entity and nominating it as the FK for your referenced child entity.

For example using code-first annotation:

```
public class Product
{
   [Key]
   public Guid ProductId {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("RecipeId")]
   public virtual Recipe Recipe {get; set;}

   public Guid RecipeId {get; set;}

   // ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use configuration via entity type configuration or overriding the DbContext's OnModelCreating to establish the foreign key with .HasForeignKey() fluent method.

Having the FK mapped this way can raise issues if you aren't careful because you now have a reference to a Recipe entity, and a separate FK reference, and must ensure these stay in sync.

Alternatively with EF 6 you can map a column for the FK without declaring the property using .Map() /w .MapKey() in the entity type configuration or OnModelCreating of the DbContext. From what I have read about EF Core this isn't an option yet.

Once you have the Recipe reference working, it will be the same for InventoryItem.

I cover off a bit on using references vs. FKs (and not both) in this post:
http://www.practicagility.com.au/2017/10/27/ef-a-1st-class-citizen-part-4-using-references-vs-keys/

Comment: perfect. Thanks for help. Its working with '[ForeignKey("RecipeId")]' approach.